# How do I run Gedit on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, macports, gtk, gedit

I have successfully installed *gedit* on my macOS Mojave via the MacPorts, but when I execute, it gives me the following and doesn't start:

```
(gedit:96701): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:41:50.162: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(gedit:96701): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:41:50.167: cannot open display:
```

It has also installed loads of dependencies. Am I still missing anything?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to install XQuartz (The X Window System for macOS).